# Doppler Radar analogRead()

Tags: arduino, signal-processing

I've been doing a project on reading doppler speed and creating velocity data. I don't have a firm background on electric engineering / signal processing but I've researched quite a bit so far. Please bear with me if I get things wrong in my explanation.

I am currently using [HB100](https://www.tindie.com/products/limpkin/hb100-doppler-speed-sensor-arduino-compatible/) and [CDM324](https://www.limpkin.fr/index.php?post/2017/02/22/Making-the-Electronics-for-a-24GHz-Doppler-Motion-Sensor) breakout model. The objective in this project is to get the voltage reading from the module and create a spectrogram though FFT in MATLAB. I got a sample data from BlackCatScience with the hand moving towards the Sensor at a fast speed. Its plot is shown below:

[Hand Speed Using Doppler Radar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCU9t.jpg)

And I've assembled my arduino kit like the picture below:

[Arduino-HB100_kit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJvjT.jpg)

> Connections are:
>
> VCC -> 5V GND -> GND FOUT -> Pin 8  VOUT -> Pin A5

So far, I found out that HB100 supports pulse/CW usage and used the code below to measure the frequency using HB100.

```
#include <MsTimer2.h>
#include <FreqMeasure.h>
//--------------GlOBAL VARIALBES---------------------
double raw_data  = FreqMeasure.read();
double sum = 0;
int count = 0; 
double raw_data_array[10];
unsigned long timeStamp = 0;

//---------------------------------------------------

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  FreqMeasure.begin();
  Serial.print("Time (ms)");
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.println("Hz");
}

void loop() {
   timer();
   freq_measure();
}

void timer() { 
   timeStamp+=1;
}

void freq_measure() { 
  while (timeStamp < 101) {
    if(FreqMeasure.available()) {
      //average readings 
      sum += FreqMeasure.read(); 
      count ++; 
      if (count > 2) { 
        float frequency = FreqMeasure.countToFrequency(sum/count);
//        Serial.print(timeStamp);
//        Serial.print("\t"); 
        Serial.println(frequency);  
        timeStamp++;
        sum = 0;
        count = 0; 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with this code is that, I want to measure the voltage reading at every, say for example, 1 millisec. However, this code is similar to using pulseIn function and the rate at which the data is out differs on whether I'm moving my hand to/from the sensor or not. When I'm not moving, the data output become slow, and when I'm moving, the data output rate is fast.

Hence, I decided to use some other code and use analogRead function like below:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
#define RADAR A5 //pin number for VOUT 
//--------------------GLOBAL VARIABLES-----------------------------
unsigned long  timeStamp;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(RADAR, INPUT); 
  Serial.println(F("Settings Complete" ));
}

void loop() {
  // 1 millisec == 0.001 second  -->  1000 millisec == 1 second
  // we want about 5 seconds of data, hence the loop runs for 5000 millisec

  while (timeStamp < 5000){
    showReading();
  }
}

void showReading() { 
//    timeStamp = millis();
//    Serial.print(timeStamp);
//    Serial.print("\t");
    //Read input on analog pin 5: 
    int sensorData = analogRead(RADAR);
//    float voltage = sensorData * (5.0 / 1023.0); 
    Serial.println(sensorData); 
}
```

This time, the serial monitor is giving me a value between 0 and 1023 and that's great, but even if I move my hand in front of the sensor, the values change but minimally. What should I do to correct this and get a plot like the graph above?

Thanks for reading such a long question. Have a great day!